# DiscordAPIError[40060]: Interaction has already been acknowledged

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am getting this, but my bot is still working. I am unsure why I am getting it.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, User } = require('discord.js');
const { QuickDB } = require('quick.db');
const db = new QuickDB();

const users = db.table('users');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('manager')
        .setDescription('Grab manament info.'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await users.all();
        await interaction.reply('You have arrived!');
    },
};
```

Still trying to learn how to post an array for my table.

I am just executing the command when it gives me that error, unsure why.

Comment: It's impossible to receive that error with the code supplied. The cause would lie elsewhere - perhaps where you're calling that function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are defering the interaction you should use

```js
await interaction.editReply('You have arrived!');
```